# Gitlab login LDAP user without e-mail

Tags: ldap, gitlab

In my organization, some users don't have an e-mail address. At the e-mail field in ActiveDirectory, they have a fake (malformed) e-mail address, something like "user.name@xx".

When these users try to login into Gitlab, they get the following error:

'Could not authorize you from LDAP because "Validation failed: email is invalid, email is invalid".'

Is there any configuration to ignore email adress checking with LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

The [issue 6230](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6230) has been tracking this:

> The mail validation on user model is performed by validation here: [`app/models/user.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/d701d5869516142a4073804622503299202cfbe2/app/models/user.rb#L53).
>
> I think you can configure your own regexp here: [`config/initializers/devise.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/d701d5869516142a4073804622503299202cfbe2/config/initializers/devise.rb#L110).

---

However, the official statement is:

> Disabling validation is not something that will be done on GitLab side. This can lead to inconsistencies in the database and could cause a plethora of issues.
>
> I suggest you :

- either fix your LDAP
- or have `allow_username_or_email_login` setting enabled: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L130

> This is issue is a support question so I will point you to the [contributing guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4413c2325ae747a9362125dbe051615b8ec697d7/CONTRIBUTING.md#issue-tracker) and close it.

---

Not directly with GitLab itself, because that error message is the result of an **[`omniauth`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)** callback: see [`config/locales/devise.en.yml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/7f03b32049e93bbe84b63ced9c8493fc2f2a0b98/config/locales/devise.en.yml#L48-L50):

```
omniauth_callbacks:
  success: 'Successfully authorized from %{kind} account.'
  failure: 'Could not authorize you from %{kind} because "%{reason}".'
```

Yet, the [Rodrigo Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3253676/rodrigo-carvalho) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459886/gitlab-login-ldap-user-without-e-mail/21460983#comment32432800_21460983):

> I actually discovered this is a Gitlab behaviour.
>
> I changed the "[`/lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5e004719c44edee3b6ab7921b016fd0044bad8b4/lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb#L52-L62)" (Gitlab code) to append a "`.com`" in the end of the invalid email address and it worked.

Comment: OK, thanks for you answer. I posted to omniauth people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462163/omniauth-ldap-logon-user-without-e-mail

Comment: I actually discovered this is a Gitlab behaviour. I changed the "/lib/gitlab/oauth/user.rb" (Gitlab code) to append a ".com" in the end of the invalid email address and it worked. Should I open a ticket on Github?

Comment: @RodrigoCarvalho Sounds great! I have included your finding to the answer for more visibility, as well as a link to the `user.rb` source code. This would be indeed a good candidate for a pull request or at least an issue for GitLab to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I opened a ticket, because my "solution" to the problem (append ".com" to the address) isn't a great one. Here is the ticket:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6230

Comment: @RodrigoCarvalho ok, I will monitor that ticket.